Cannot import name '_check_array_key' from 'skfda._utils' in Python 3.12.7
I am trying to use skfda library in my python code. I have already installed the package using `pip install scikit-fda, however, the error was a little bit strange for me. Can anyone explain why this keeps showing and how to fix this error? Thank you so much!
from skfda.preprocessing.dim_reduction import variable_selection
import skfda

mrmr = variable_selection.MinimumRedundancyMaximumRelevance(n_features_to_select=70,method="MIQ")

Exception has occurred: ImportError
cannot import name '\_check_array_key' from 'skfda.\_utils' (c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\skfda\\\_utils\\\_\_init\_\_.py)
  File "D:\ShiroSnipee\Study\Python\Project\sample.py", line 68, in <module>
    mrmr = variable_selection.MinimumRedundancyMaximumRelevance(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ImportError: cannot import name '\_check_array_key' from 'skfda.\_utils' (c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\skfda\\\_utils\\\_\_init\_\_.py)

